# What would you make of a recuiter/HR person who does not call at scheduled time?

Tags: interviewing

I am wondering what would you make of a recruiter who does this?

I know that it is possible that they got busy and forgot to call but isn't this unprofessional and annoying for the candidate (me in this case). Giving the benefit of the doubt of "something else came up for them" what should I do when this happens?

Comment: Well, what would be the outcome if you blew them off? Would they give you a second chance?

Comment: Are they calling you late or are they simply not calling you at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had this happen many time over the last few months.  Typically recruiters get pulled into last minute meeting or meetings run long.   Remember, most of the time you are not the only person they are working with and sometimes not the only person they are putting up for the same job.  There are lots of balls in the air.  I opt to take the patient and understanding route which shows I am willing to work with them, and not get all uppity due to a slight annoyance which can only play to my advantage when they describe me to the potential employer.

Comment: Sure, if they are a bit late or email an apology to reschedule, those kinds of things are acceptable to an extent. But just blowing you off isn't. If you are not that important to them, why should they be that important to you?